# Linux grep pipe

Tags: shell, pipe

I have a input.txt file containing a list of number:

```
1719
194
1719
1719
194
1135
194
```

I want to create a output.txt using a grep pipe in order to sort them in ascending order of the number of appearance, namely:

```
194: 3 times
1719: 2 times
1135: 1 time.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the numbers are in 6910460.txt without empty lines:

```
$ cat 6910460.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
3  194
2 1719
1 1135
```

Or if you need the text "times" as well, you can append an awk command:

```
$ cat 6910460.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | \
    awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=" "} \
        {temp=$2; $2=$1; $1=temp} {printf "%4i %4i time(s)\n", $1, $2}'
```

Which would print:

```
 194    3 time(s)
1719    2 time(s)
1135    1 time(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    {count[$0]++} 
    END {for (n in count) {print n ": " count[n] " times"}}
' file |
sort -nr -k2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "1719
194
1719
1719
194
1135
194" | sort -n | uniq -c 
      3 194
      1 1135
      3 1719
```

Is this sufficient, or can you switch the values yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got Linux at hand at the moment, but would something like this work:

```
cat input.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -g
```

Comment: Since appearance frequencies are all integers, there isn't really a good reason to use the slower floating point with `sort -g`.  Stick with `-n`.